# Splitting a comma separated value in a QueryString into 2 results

Tags: jquery, string, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a set of two numeric strings separated by a comma, which I need to put into two separate fields. Because their length is variable, I cannot just use a `Left()` or `Right()` separation. Existing answers go part way, but I get *lost* when trying to use them. Project is in *Classic ASP* with *jQuery*. Data is posted as *price* and I need to split the first set to *minpric*', and the second set to *maxprice*.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a source code sample that illustrate your problem.

Comment: @cubitouch: My QueryString contains '&price=1500,35000' and I have yet to have any working code other than reading the QueryString value into an array called 'price'.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to here? Are trying to split them in the vb code, in the js, or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: If they are comma delimited, can't you just search the string for that character and work from there?  That's the whole point of delimiters, right?

Comment: @mituw16 Yes, that is what I am tring to do - split them into vbScript

JoeM That is probably exactly what I need to do, but I am not sure how :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript:

Use Split() to split a string on a separator:

```
>> sq = "&price=1500,35000"
>> sp = Split(sq, "=")(1)
>> ap = Split(sp, ",")
>> np1 = CLng(ap(0))
>> np2 = CLng(ap(1))
>> WScript.Echo np1, np2
>>
1500 35000
```

J(ava)Script:

There should be a String.split(SeparatorAsStringOrRegExp) method that does the same.

Comment: +1 cleaner than my answer.  I forgot about `Split()`.

Comment: Oh yes! Much cleaner. Love it! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If they are comma delimited, you can find that character and work from its location. Something like this:

```
Dim nEqualPos, nCommaPos, strToSearch, strMinPrice, strMaxPrice

strToSearch = "&price=1500,35000"
nEqualPos = InStr(strToSearch, "=")
nCommaPos = InStr(strToSearch, ",")
strMinPrice = Mid(strToSearch, nEqualPos + 1, (nCommaPos - nEqualPos) - 1)
strMaxPrice = Mid(strToSearch, nCommaPos + 1)
```

You could adding looping and such, but this is the essential piece in VBScript.

Comment: Thank you very much for that JoeM. Works a treat.